# Is a variable read from a file different from a hardcoded string?

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

see this code

```
PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT = choice(proxies).rstrip().split(":")

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

# Direct = 0, Manual = 1, PAC = 2, AUTODETECT = 4, SYSTEM = 5
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", PROXY_PORT)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port", PROXY_PORT)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port", PROXY_PORT)
```

proxies is a list of proxies in form `123.123.123.123:1234\n`. The weird thing is, if i hardcode the two variables `PROXY_HOST` and `PROXY_PORT` it will use a proxy, if i try to read it from a file which i do like this

```
with open("proxies.txt") as f:
    proxies = f.readlines()
```

the proxy settings are ignored. If i print the two vars, they are correct but not used.

So is there something I don't see, how is it different to hardcode the ip and port or to read it from a file/list.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean, but I supose you are having problems with reading from a file, since maybe the last character of each file line is \n, or something like that. Regards,

Comment: What do you hardcode them to, and what is an example content of the file?

Comment: Please show us `proxies` in case this list is hardcoded vs. `proxies` in case you read it from file. Best would be to print both varialbes using `repr()`.

Comment: what i meant by hardcoded is that:     PROXY_HOST = "123.123.123.123", same goes for the port. Give me a minute I'll post some more info

Comment: ok - @Jan-PhilipGehrcke pointed me to the solution, thanks a lot: the proxy port was a string after reading it, I just had to convert it to an integer

Comment: rootman: You should post that as your own answer (Oor Jan-PhilipGehrcke should) and accept it.

Comment: Actually @Jan-PhilipGehrcke should do it, he was the one who pointed me to it - i will see if he does it in the next few hours and if not i'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a how-do-I-properly-debug-issue. Look exactly at `proxies` in case this list is hardcoded vs. `proxies` in case you read it from file. Best would be to print both varialbes using `repr()`. You'll see a difference. The solution will be very simple: after reading the port from a file, it still is a string and needs to be converted to an integer. When you hardcode it, you define it as an integer in the first place.

Comment: You should post the actual result (that the proxy port was a string but it had been hardcoded as an integer) in this answer

Comment: The whole "thread" turned out to be weird. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines` retains the line-end character for each line.  It's possible this is causing the proxy setting to silently fail if the port is set to, e.g. `"1234\n"`.

Comment: i tried to get rid of this issue using rstrip(), but maybe there is more that i don't see. I'll look into it

Comment: @rootman: As others have suggested, you need to show us exactly what you have the variables hardcoded to and exactly what the contents of the file are.